Register initial value without explicit reset input (Verilog)
In this question, the following code was presented:
module PISO(input clk ,input [7:0] par_in, output reg out_bit);
    reg [7:0] mem = 8'b00000000;
    reg [2:0] count = 3'b000;
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
            if (count == 3'b000) begin
                    mem <= par_in;
                    count <= 3'b111;
            end else begin
                    out_bit <= mem[0];
                    mem <= mem >> 1;
                    count <= count - 1;
            end
    end
endmodule

Is this old answer still correct? To achieve reliable and portable initialization, an explicit reset input should be implemented?

It depends. If you want portability with every possible synthesis tool on the planet, then yes, you still need to use an explicit reset. But realize explicit resets take up extra area and power. If the initialization is only for simulation, tools have ways of randomly initializing state variables so your counter does not stay in the X state.
If you are only doing FPGAs, most FPGA synthesis tools convert initilizations to power-on states.
